# Two Applications With Same Jwt Token For Authentication

Tags: c#, jwt, authorization, token, http-status-code-401

I had one extensive application with JWT authentication, now I converted it to two different applications like A and B.

JWT authentication is something like this :

```
 private string GenerateToken(UserVM user)
        {
            var token = new JwtTokenBuilder()
                .AddSecurityKey(ApplicationTokens.Tokens["Pa"])
                .AddSubject(user.UserName)
                .AddIssuer("Farz.ad")
                .AddAudience("Pa")
                .AddClaim("username", user.UserName)
                .AddClaim("display-name", $"{user.FirstName} {user.LastName}")
                .AddExpiry(1000)
                .Build();

            return token.Value;
        }
```

and in another code, I have something like this :

```
 ApplicationTokens.Tokens["Pa"] = JwtSecurityKey.Create("Abcd1234");
```

my problem is that now they are using the same secret key, and it's possible to use the authentication code of A api to B's api without login in B application.

and also I Use theses method **GenerateToken** in some other Controller.

I just Change this *Abcd1234* in application A, but after this change, api methods of application A give me a 401 unauthorized error.

I think something else must be changed too, but I don't know.